# How to change a drop-down-menu item to a selection item

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, opencart

i want to change the dropdown language item in opencart to a static selection model, so both languages can be shown always and the user doesnt have to hover on the language flag to see the other language.

So I think i should change the language file in theme, and in following you can see the code, so what parts should i change? I believe I should change the type of the item from dropdown to something else?

```
<div id="language">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-hover="dropdown">
            <?php echo $current_language; ?> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php foreach ($languages as $language): ?>
                <?php if ($type === 'flag'): ?>
                    <li><a onclick="$(this).closest('form').find('input[name=\'code\']').val('<?php echo $language['code']; ?>'); $(this).closest('form').submit();"><img width="16" height="11" src="<?php echo Journal2Utils::staticAsset('image/flags/' . $language['image']); ?>" alt="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a programming question this is more of a task that you're looking for someone to do for you for free.

You should look for an extension in the marketplace (https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension) and if there isn't one you should pay a developer from the Commercial Forum (https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=88).

Comment: that is probably completely true, but I didnt find any extension which does this, so i decided to do this myself and learn how to do it

Comment: Ok but StackOverflow is not designed to guide you through a project it is designed to help with very specific small programming questions. You might get more help on the OpenCart General Support Forum: https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=190 where someone maybe kind enough to guide you through but you will need to do most of the hard work yourself if you are not willing to pay someone.